# How to build a mongoose query that includes an "or" operator

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to build a mongoose query that will retrieve documents that contain references to any objects whose ids I pass to the query. I am trying to build a query object that includes the `$or` operator.

My main document contains an attribute which is an array of references to other objects i.e. its schema contains

```
tags: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Tag'}],
```

I want to build a query that returns all documents that contain at least one of the tags whose ids I pass into the query - something like.

```
{"tags":{ $or: ["5759406a4b9b1eb474c25ce4","5759406a4b9b1eb474c25ce3"]} }
```

which I can pass into the `model.find` method.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the $in operator:

```
<doc-name>.find({tags: {$in: ["id","id"]} })...
```

or

```
<doc-name>.find().where("tags").in(["id","id"])...
```

Comment: I am trying to build a generic model controller which will convert the HTTP query parameters into a mongoose query object.  So how would I build the object "{tags: {$in: ["id","id"]} } programmatically if I received something like &tags=id1,id2 in the query string.

Comment: just pass the array into your query: `var array = ["id","id"]; <docname>.find().where("tags").in(array)...` Did I get your question right?

Comment: I think you do understand the question but I was trying to avoid using the find().where option and instead construct a query object as in your first example - <doc-name>.find({tags: {$in: ["id","id"]} })... I cannot seem to achieve this in a way that Mongoose allows  - and Mongoose throws an error "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"57594885b062ef6440c0469e,57594885b062ef6440c0469d\" at path \"tags\""

Comment: `var array = ["id","id"]; <docname>.find({tags: {$in: array}})....` Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to split the comma separated query params into an array: `var params = "id,id,id"; var array = params.split(','); <doc-name>.find({tags: {$in: array}})....`

Comment: Actually it was a mistake on my part  - building a query object like below does work and is giving me what I need  

{"tags":{$in: ["575964e05f50c5dc77d47593","575964e05f50c5dc77d47592"]}}

this is returning any document with either of the supplied tags
 
thanks for the help anyway